# Safe way to save user specific data / access token on android device

Tags: android, xamarin, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I'm looking for a safer way to keep signed in user specific information on device, I want to make sure this information can not be retrieved.
I found one solution i.e. `string filename = "userId.txt";

```
        var personalData = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        if (!Directory.Exists(personalData))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exist.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory exists.");
            File.AppendAllText(personalData + @"/" + filename, String.Format("{0}={1}", key, value));
        }`
```

Is this the correct way of doing what I want? or I should consider SQL Lite?
Can anyone please guide, I'm just beginner to android/Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something really quick and cross-platform I would suggest this plugin: https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage.
It uses KeyStore on Android and Key-chain in iOS to save data.

I´m using it in Android and iOS with no issues. Implementation takes less than 5 minutes and I use it to store the access token of my oAuth2 flow.
The downside is that you need to hardcode the security password and that´s something someone could reverse-engineer to access your data. A workaround for that (if you really need that level of security) is to retrieve the security key from your server once per session, but that may be an issue when the device network is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).
If you want not-so-secure method - use [Shared preferences](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference). Here is google [description](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) 
And if you want some cross-platform way, there is Xamarin.Forms [recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/).